# В каких случаях можно использовать слово дискография?

Tags: музыка

Можно ли слово дискография использовать как название для всех песен и альбомов групп и артистов одной компании/лейбла? Или это будет неправильным вариантом?
Тогда чем можно заменить это слово?

Comment: Вы не туда написали. Тут ресурс о программировании

Comment: Возможно вам сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/   ну или что-то из этого:  https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме ресурса. Возможно нужно обратиться в https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Вполне можно, см. [вики: Дискография](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), но в целом вопрос не по теме )